# Submit change password form in bootstrap modal through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a change password form which I have tried to code so that it gets submitted through ajax.
I needed to do validation too.
Below is the code that I've written. Is there anyway so that we can use this js ajax function for multiple modal forms?
Or will we need to create a seperate function for submitting each modal form?

**Also I wanted to make the parent page reload after user closes the modal so I have added this code:**

```
$('#edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

**but it reloads the page when someone clicks cancel button too. Is there any way to prevent reloading when clicking cancel button and only do reloading only by clicking "x".**

Here is the code

index.php file where the modal is

```
<p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" data-original-title="Edit">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Edit</span>
    </button>
</p>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Your Detail</h4>
            </div>
            <!--/.modal-header-->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="updateForm" action="update-info.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer_name">Customer Name :</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" value="<?php echo $userRow['fullName']; ?>" />
                    </div>

                    <h4><u><strong>Change Password</strong></u></h4>
                    <div class="form-group" id="currentPass-group">
                        <label for="current_pass">Current Password :</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="current_pass" id="current_pass">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="new_pass">New Password :</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="new_pass" id="new_pass">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirm_pass">Confirm Password :</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm_pass" id="confirm_pass">
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-warning" value="Save changes" /> -->
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitForm" value="Save changes">Save Changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/.modal -->
```

custom.js file:

```
$('#edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    location.reload();
});

/* must apply only after HTML has loaded */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updateForm").on("submit", function(e) {

        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;
        var currentpass = $("#current_pass").val();
        var newpass = $("#new_pass").val();
        var cnfpass = $("#confirm_pass").val();

        if (currentpass == '') {
            $("#current_pass").after('<span class="error text-danger"><em>Please  enter your current password.</em></span>');
            //$('#currentPass-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
            //$('#current_pass').append('<div class="help-block">Please enter your current password.</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
            hasError = true;
        } else if (newpass == '') {
            $("#new_pass").after('<span class="error text-danger"><em>Please enter a password.</em></span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (cnfpass == '') {
            $("#confirm_pass").after('<span class="error text-danger"><em>Please re-enter your password.</em></span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (newpass != cnfpass) {
            $("#confirm_pass").after('<span class="error text-danger"><em>Passwords do not match.</em></span>');
            hasError = true;
        }

        if (hasError == true) {
            return false;
        }
        if (hasError == false) {

            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#edit .modal-header .modal-title').html("Result");
                    $('#edit .modal-body').html(data);
                    $("#submitForm").remove();
                    //document.location.reload();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                    console.log(status + ": " + error);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $("#submitForm").on('click', function() {
        $("#updateForm").submit();
    });
});
```

update-info.php

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault();` after `$("#updateForm").on("submit", function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

To use this code for multiple form add ajax code in one function and call that function whenever you want to.

To prevent page from reloading when someone click on cancel
Instead of using

```
 $('#edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    location.reload();
    });
```

Add one click event on cross and then reload page by location.reload();

Comment: Thanks !! But where will I place validation then? Since it will be different for each form.

Comment: You can add your validation on submit event and after validation you can call function from that event with all form parameters, that function consist of ajax request code.

Comment: Thanks !! I made the function for ajax code and it worked.

Comment: How can we have all the php processing code in one file. Since I am using this

Comment: if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){  in php code, how can i distinguish from other forms processing code?

Comment: Use <input type="submit" value="xxx" name="submit"> different value for different forms and based on those value you have if condition. if($_POST['submit'] == "xxx"){}

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.preventDefault(); and instead of submit use click event

```
$("#submitForm").on("click", function(e) {   
         e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: How would click even help ? Instead of using submit?

Comment: submit will directly submit form and you don't want to submit form, you want to first validation and then ajax call. and if you tried, it definately work

Comment: Also I want to add has-error class in the fileds if it has some error, so for this would I need to add seperate ID for each form-group?